# How can i make buttons Enabled & Gridview with binded data only when i select a value from POPUP and click on OK

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, popup

I am having a form with search button when i click on that i will have a pop-up opened with some list of EmpID and when i click on ok i will prompt the user the selected one. When the user clicks on ok on that then only i would like to enable the buttons on the form
and also i would like to show the gridview with binded data selected on particular ID
Ma Java script

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function GetData(Name)
{
 var Hiddval=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1").value;
 document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmpSearch").value=Name;
 alert(Hiddval);
 return false;
}
```

My code for button click is as follows

```
   protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script>window.open('cliEditEmployee.aspx',null,'height=300px,width=390px,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no');</script>");
    BtnEmployeeData.Enabled = true;
    btnEmployeePersonlData.Enabled = true;
    btnSalaryinfo.Visible = true;
    btnW4Form.Enabled = true;
    btnBankdata.Enabled = true;

}
```

So can any one give me an better idea to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are enabling the buttons right after window.open, no matter what they did in the new window; perhaps you should do that upon clicking the OK from the child window, you can use the window.opener to have access to the parent DOM

Comment: Can i have a sample code or can you tell where i have to do changes in my code

Comment: this tutorial should give you some idea http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html